# AMP equivalent for analytics anonymizeIp

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

I need to anonimaze my google analytics stats on AMP page

what is the AMP json equivalent for standard analytics code?

```
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the hits to Google Analytics from AMP are anonymized by default. There is no way to override this.

See https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/0.1/vendors.js

```
'basePrefix': 'v=1&_v=a0&aip=true&_s=${requestCount}&' +
```